# How do I draw graphs?

Tags: plot

I'm new to Latex and I think I am going to use it for my physics classes in school. I have found a really good template: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/aip/
(I use sharelatex) which is great equationwise and such, but I don't seem to be able to draw a graph. I want to draw a distance-time graph but I don't know how to do it!

How would I go on to do that?

Answer (score 4):

An example of the height-time graph of an object thrown upward vertically.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\pstVerb
{
    /U 20 def
    /G -10 def
}
\psset{yunit=.5cm}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(5,21)
    \psaxes[Dy=5](0,0)(4.5,21.5)[$t$ {[\si{\s}]},0][$h$ {[\si{\m}]},90]
    \psplot[algebraic,linecolor=blue]{0}{4}{U*x+G/2*x^2}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In this example, the object is thrown at an initial speed  20 meter per second vertically upward under the influence of earth gravity of 10 meter per second squared.

### Just for fun!

Compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape animation.tex`.

```
% This file name is animation.tex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{frames.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\pstVerb
{
    /U 20 def
    /G -10 def
}
\def\h(#1){U*#1+G/2*#1^2}
\psset{yunit=.5cm}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\multido{\n=.0+.4}{11}{%
\begin{pspicture}(5,21)
    \psaxes[Dy=5](0,0)(4.5,21.5)[$t$ {[\si{\s}]},0][$h$ {[\si{\m}]},90]
    \psplot[algebraic,linecolor=blue]{0}{4}{\h(x)}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=gray](\n,0)(*{\n} {\h(x)})(0,0|*{\n} {\h(x)})
    \pscircle*[linecolor=red](0,0|*{\n} {\h(x)}){3pt}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{animate,pgffor}
\foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,ps2pdf/ps}{\immediate\write18{\compiler\space frames.\ext}}
\begin{document}
\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,scale=1]{1}{frames}{}{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the trajectory of the moving object is a straight line, not a parabola! That is a common misunderstanding that many students have.

Comment: "common misunderstanding" ?

Comment: @kan: Yes. It is a common misunderstanding for most students.

Answer (score 3):

Graphics can be drawn with a number of systems, including [PGF/TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), [PSTricks](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-base) and [Asymptote](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/asymptote).

Graphs (ie plots) can be drawn with [PGFPlots](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots), [PST-2dplot](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-2dplot) and [PST-3dplot](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-3dplot).

There are most likely other drawing packages that I'm not aware of; have a look around [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org).

Answer (score 3):

As a followup to ChrisS, I would PGFPlots for this. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

Position vs time graph:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot  {5+10*x-5*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

with some styling options:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines = middle,smooth,xlabel = $t$ (\si{\s}), ylabel =$y$ (\si{\m}), minor tick num =1, grid=both, no markers]
\addplot +[domain=0:3] {5+10*x-5*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]