# tikz figure on beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

How could we make the following figure, while having in each "click" one curve with a comment for it, and at the end having the whole shape?

[image]

**For the tikz figure**
How could I make curves in that way as showing middle income in the middle (between low and high income)?

Comment: You should check [this topic](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1538/policy-on-how-do-i-draw-this-questions).

Comment: And you can start from [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140748/36821). I don't really understand anything in your question. What is a "click"? What do you mean by "comment for it"? What is that gray background stuff?

Comment: One idea might be solution 1 in [Does TikZ support interactive animation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98446/13304).

Comment: This figure reminds me: [create xkcd style diagram in tex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74878/create-xkcd-style-diagram-in-tex?lq=1)